# Visual Studio 2015 schema comparison can't connect

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using VS 2015, trying to run a schema comparison on two SQL Server 2014 databases. After I specify each connection and click Compare, I get the error "Unable to restore the password. Enter a password by editing the connection." Each connection is saving the password; I'm using SQL Server Authentication, Integrated Security=False. What else can I check to see why it won't connect?
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server Data Tools are you using (this can be found in Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio)?

Comment: I'm getting the same error with SQL Server Data Tools v. 14.0.60519.0. It's able to connect using the same username/password to a different database on the server. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be an issue with SSDT tools v14 saving the connection details. Until a proper fix is available you need to clean up the registry keys each time. **NOTE**: close Visual Studio before following these steps, otherwise the registry keys will be recreated immediately after you delete them.

> 1) go to registry on key
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SSDT\ConnectionStrings and delete
>   your content only (all values inside this key)
>
> 2) go to key
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SSDT\ConnectionStringsUpgrade and
>   change value from 1 to 0
>
> 3) go to VS and redo connection into Schema Compare WITHOUT using
>   history (ie. select the connection again using "Select Source..." in the dropdown). This will do VS to write new connection into
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SSDT\ConnectionStrings and
>   rewrite value 1 into
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SSDT\ConnectionStringsUpgrade
>
> 4) if you want create another connection on VS into Schema Compare,
>   simply repeat steps 2 and 3.
>
> Now, just use the connections on the history of VS in the Schema
>   Compare window.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/74d2b7f0-09f2-4ef3-935b-e0a1e0e8fb82/schema-compare-target-unavailable?forum=ssdt